# SQL Server: Sum of Calculated Row within N Months

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL Server and have a question regarding summing over a calculated row with a conditional statement.

My data is organized as follows:

```
ID  S_DATE     END_DATE   MNum  CHG  DateCHG
---------------------------------------------
1   1/26/2001   2/26/2001   7   NULL   1
1   2/27/2001   3/27/2001   8   1      1
1   3/28/2001   1/9/2003    9   1      21
1   1/10/2003   3/2/2004    11  2      14
1   3/3/2004    10/14/2004  10  -1     7
1   10/15/2004  6/22/2005   9   -1     8
1   6/23/2005   3/9/2008    8   -1    33
1   3/10/2008   1899-12-30  0   NULL    -1299
2   9/23/1993   9/11/2000   3   NULL    84
2   1/1/1999    12/31/1998  3   0   -1
2   9/12/2000   11/13/2001  2   -1  14
2   11/14/2001  1899-12-30  0   NULL    -1223
```

`DateCHG` is equal to the number of months between S_DATE & End_Date. I would like to find the SUM of CHG for each ID where the CHG occurs within 3 months of previous date.

Here is my current code (NOTE: Column headers are different from data above for formatting purposes. Also I cannot write to this database so only in Query format)

```
SELECT
     *,  
     CASE 
        WHEN MratingNum = 0 OR
             LAG(MratingNum) OVER (OVER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) = 0 OR 
             MAST_ISSU_NUM <> LAG(MAST_ISSU_NUM) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) --OR
            --LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) < 12 OR  --By Credit Rating
            --LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) < 18
           THEN NULL 
           ELSE CAST(MratingNum AS INT) - LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME)
    END AS CHG,
    DATEDIFF(month, RATG_DATETIME, RATG_END_DATETIME) AS DateCHG 
FROM
    MOODYS_DRD.dbo.DEBT_RATG AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    sandbox.dbo.RatingMap AS t2 ON t1.RATG_TXT = t2.MratingValue
WHERE 
    RATG_TYP_CD = 'LT'
ORDER BY 
    MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME
```

So for example the output would look something like this:

```
ID S_DATE   .... SumCHG
1  1/26/2001....   NULL
1  2/27/2001....   NULL
1  3/28/2001....   2
1  1/10/2003....   NULL
1  3/3/2004 ....   NULL
```

I'm assuming the best approach is to calculate a rolling sum of DateCHG where it is less than 3 and then SUM the CHG column? Thanks all!

EDIT: This is fairly complex so let me try another way of asking the question. For each record I want to look back and find the SUM of CHG within 3 months of the S_DATE. For 3/28/2001, this would include 2/01 and 1/01. The MNum went from 7 to 9 so the SUM of CHG would be 2. However from 3/04, there were no changes in the past 3 months so return NULL. I obviously want to do this per ID so don't want to overlap 3 months from ID 2 to 1. Hope this makes more sense now?

Comment: How is your output example what it is you asked for? You asked for total of SumChg for each ID, so you will only have ID =1 returned once.

Comment: @Edward by each ID meaning I don't want to overlap amongst IDs. I want to look at every row, and find the sum for everything within the previous 3 months. If there are only 2 rows per ID and they are 6 months apart I want to return NULL. If there are 20 rows for an ID and the there are 2 'clumps' of data where they are within 3 months I want to find the sum for each of those clumps. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: not really. What do you mean by clump?  by overlapping I would think you mean you don't want to mix ID=1 with ID=2. Please check my answer and let me know from there what it isn't doing you are trying to accomplish..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t0` and `t` are used for setting up the data.

```
with    t0
          as ( select   *
               from     ( values ( 1, '1/26/2001', '2/26/2001', 7, null, 1),
                        ( 1, '2/27/2001', '3/27/2001', 8, 1, 1),
                        ( 1, '3/28/2001', '1/9/2003', 9, 1, 21),
                        ( 1, '1/10/2003', '3/2/2004', 11, 2, 14),
                        ( 1, '3/3/2004', '10/14/2004', 10, -1, 7),
                        ( 1, '10/15/2004', '6/22/2005', 9, -1, 8),
                        ( 1, '6/23/2005', '3/9/2008', 8, -1, 33),
                        ( 1, '3/10/2008', '1899-12-30', 0, null, -1299),
                        ( 2, '9/23/1993', '9/11/2000', 3, null, 84),
                        ( 2, '1/1/1999', '12/31/1998', 3, 0, -1),
                        ( 2, '9/12/2000', '11/13/2001', 2, -1, 14),
                        ( 2, '11/14/2001', '1899-12-30', 0, null, -1223) ) t ( ID, S_DATE, END_DATE, MNum, CHG, DateCHG )
             ),
        t as ( select   t0.ID ,
                        cast(t0.S_DATE as date) S_DATE ,
                        cast(t0.END_DATE as date) END_DATE ,
                        t0.MNum ,
                        t0.CHG ,
                        t0.DateCHG
               from     t0
             )
    select  case when Cnt >= 3 then p.CHG
            end SumCHG,
            *
    from    t
            outer apply ( select    sum(u.CHG) CHG ,
                                    count(*) Cnt
                          from      t u
                          where     u.ID = t.ID
                                    and u.S_DATE between dateadd(month, -3,
                                                              t.S_DATE)
                                                 and     t.S_DATE
                        ) p
    order by t.ID ,
        t.S_DATE;
```

Use CTE for your tables,

```
;with t as (
SELECT
     *,  
     CASE 
        WHEN MratingNum = 0 OR
             LAG(MratingNum) OVER (OVER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) = 0 OR 
             MAST_ISSU_NUM <> LAG(MAST_ISSU_NUM) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) --OR
            --LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) < 12 OR  --By Credit Rating
            --LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME) < 18
           THEN NULL 
           ELSE CAST(MratingNum AS INT) - LAG(MratingNum) OVER (ORDER BY MAST_ISSU_NUM, RATG_DATETIME)
    END AS CHG,
    DATEDIFF(month, RATG_DATETIME, RATG_END_DATETIME) AS DateCHG 
FROM
    MOODYS_DRD.dbo.DEBT_RATG AS t1
LEFT JOIN
    sandbox.dbo.RatingMap AS t2 ON t1.RATG_TXT = t2.MratingValue
WHERE 
    RATG_TYP_CD = 'LT'
)
    select  case when Cnt >= 3 then p.CHG
            end SumCHG,
            *
    from    t
            outer apply ( select    sum(u.CHG) CHG ,
                                    count(*) Cnt
                          from      t u
                          where     u.ID = t.ID
                                    and u.S_DATE between dateadd(month, -3,
                                                              t.S_DATE)
                                                 and     t.S_DATE
                        ) p
    order by t.ID ,
        t.S_DATE;
```

Comment: I feel like this is on the right path but I'm not sure how to incorporate into my existing code? I'm still very new to SQL and not sure where the syntax belongs...

Comment: Just start from the `select` part. Change `t` to `yourDataSource t`.

Comment: What's your name btw?

Comment: Invalid object name 'u' - trying a bunch of iterations to see which works. The CHG field is calculated from another SELECT and I'm not sure if I adjusted it correctly. In any case, you can email me at nyobna at gmail regarding name, obviously don't want to share it in open forum :)

Comment: for the `from      t u`, just change `t` to your data source.

Comment: TYVM! But the CHG field in u.CHG is calculated earlier in the same code (it is not native data to the table and I cannot alter the original table) so I received an 'invalid column' error. The original code is posted above and hence my earlier question on where to put it.